# How to print the header value only one time in the column and leave blank until next headers in the csv while converting from json to csv

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a `python` code for converting `json` into `csv` file.
When I converted I am able to see the particular heading gets printed in the consecutive columns where I don't need that.

My python code:

```
import json, csv, datetime

f = open('cost_drilldown_data.json')
data = json.load(f)
s = csv.writer(open('cd23old.csv', 'w'))
s.writerow(["filter", "cost", "value", "cost", "subvalue", "cost", "time", "cost"])

for breakdown in data['breakdown']:
    for time in data['time']:
        for values in breakdown['values']:
            if 'subvalues' in values:
                for subvalues in values['subvalues']:
                    s.writerow([breakdown['filter'],
                                breakdown["cost"],
                                values['value'],
                                values['cost'],
                                subvalues["subvalue"],
                                subvalues["cost"],
                                time["time"][0]["time"],
                                time["cost"]]
                               )
            else:
                s.writerow([breakdown['filter'], "", "", values['value'], values['cost']])
```

> My actual output in csv:
>
> ```
> filter,cost,value,cost,subvalue,cost,time,cost
> tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-16,112.793
> tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-17,112.748
> tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-18,112.739
> tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-19,107.165
> account,628455167342,1613.508,,
> account,85f05078-74e0-4015-aad3-84ff7e111023,1341.397,,
> project_id,813,2954.905,,
> provider,aws,1613.508,,
> provider,azure,1341.397,,
> ```
>
> BUT I EXPECT TO BE IS LIKE THIS:
>
> ```
> filter,cost,value,cost,subvalue,cost,time,cost
> tags,     5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-16,112.793
>           5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-17,112.748
>           5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-18,112.739
> account,  628455167342,1613.508,
>           628455167342,1613.508,
> provider ,aws,1613.508,,
>           aws,1613.508,
> ```

I want only the filter header in left has to be printed only a single time.
How can I do this any help appreciated!!!

Comment: CSV is _**flat**_ File format and not intended to be read by Human. Your wanted Reporting View could be done writing xlsx or HTML.

Comment: @ Everyone , Any other way even i dont want one headers but how to add to date time in it.I was able to add #### in place of date but date is not getting printed

Comment: [Edit] your Question and add a example what you want to do with `Datetime`, show expected Output.

Comment: @stovfl , yes i want to add the date in csv from json thats why i am using it . Ok will do the changes.